# Location information in Twitter Json Data

Tags: json, twitter, geolocation

I have streamed a number of Twitter JSON data and would like to have users' geographic info. I tried to use fields named `location` and `place`, but none of them is perfect.. My question: Is there a better way to collect this user geographic info? Thanks in advance!

It seems like field name `location` is defined as "the user-defined location for this account’s profile. Not necessarily a location nor parseable. This field will occasionally be fuzzily interpreted by the Search service." However, its value is NOT VERY CLEAN and hard to parse city, county, state, country names...

```
"location":"San Francisco, CA"
```

Another option is to reply on the field `place` which is "Nullable. When present, indicates that the tweet is associated". However, this field is not always available.

```
"place":
{
    "attributes":{},
     "bounding_box":
    {
        "coordinates":
        [[
                [-77.119759,38.791645],
                [-76.909393,38.791645],
                [-76.909393,38.995548],
                [-77.119759,38.995548]
        ]],
        "type":"Polygon"
    },
     "country":"United States",
     "country_code":"US",
     "full_name":"Washington, DC",
     "id":"01fbe706f872cb32",
     "name":"Washington",
     "place_type":"city",
     "url": "http://api.twitter.com/1/geo/id/01fbe706f872cb32.json"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's the problem with getting geolocation from twitter, you won't be able to find perfect information.

If the user has `None` for his `geo` you're next bet is `"full_name":"Washington, DC"`. The information that you'll be obtaining isn't 100% reliable but it's a starting point.

Don't use `location` since that's set by the user, instead use `full_name`. Even if a user that has geo enabled for his tweets might provide them for one, doesn't guarantee he'll have it for the next.

Comment: Thanks so much for the confirmation! That is really a shame that Twitter does not provide those type of data...

Comment: It's really based on the user more than Twitter. They have been trying to improve their geolocation, but privacy plays a big role in that.